# Kingfisher Framework not downloading image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to set the image of an imageView using `kf_setImageWithURL`

```
let url = NSURL("myurl")
someImage.kf_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil, optionsInfo: [.Transition(ImageTransition.Fade(1))],                               
progressBlock:{ receivedSize, totalSize in
                                    print("1): \(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
        },
 completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
                                    print(image)
                                    print("1): Finished")

    })
```

When I try to open it in a browser the image loads properly. But for some reason the image in the completionHandler is always nil and I'm not able to set the image of my image view. Would be great if anyone can point out what's going wrong here.

**UPDATE**

I tried printing the error message in the block and got this

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not
>   found on this server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x134637690 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1100 "(null)"},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///http:/192.168.10.125/animapp/uploads/1458219536306null1.1458219542.jpg,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///http:/192.168.10.125/animapp/uploads/1458219536306null1.1458219542.jpg,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this
>   server.}

Comment: can you link to the the kingifsher framework?

Comment: @Shubhank https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher this is the framework

Comment: can you check if there is error in completion closure ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my question.

Comment: pretty sure `file://` isnt valid url for a network request.. in browser it will load a file from the storage. it won't on the device.

Comment: I'm not adding `file://` in the url. I think it's being automatically being appended by the method. Thanks will look into it!

Comment: You can check why the image url has a null in the middle of it file:///http:/192.168.10.125/animapp/uploads/1458219536306`null`1.1458219542.jpg

Comment: That wasn't the issue. I found the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with the way I was setting the URL. I was setting the url like this

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "myurl")
```

This kept adding `-- file:///` at the end of the url. It worked perfectly when I changed it to

```
let url = NSURL(string: "myurl")
```